# Select query result in single row comma separated format

Tags: sql, select, oracle10g

I have a table and values as following example and when i select, i need the result to be available in single row with comma separated.

Table1.new_field
value1
value2
value3

I need the result as following for the select query.

value1, value2, value3...

I checked functions like wm_concat but no luck. I am using oracle 10g. Please suggest how to achieve this.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function in MySQL. But unluckily there is no builtin function for that in oracle.

You might want to check this article: [GROUP_CONCAT in Oracle 10g](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/05/group_concat-in-oracle-10g/) and [this one](http://halisway.blogspot.com/2006/08/oracle-groupconcat-updated-again.html)

```
with data
 as
 (
  select job,
    ename,
    row_number() over (partition by job order by ename) rn,
    count(*) over (partition by job) cnt
  from emp
 )
 select job, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(ename,','),',') scbp
  from data
  where rn = cnt
  start with rn = 1
  connect by prior job = job and prior rn = rn-1
  order by job
/

JOB       SCBP
--------- ----------------------------------------
ANALYST   FORD,SCOTT
CLERK     ADAMS,JAMES,MILLER,SMITH
MANAGER   BLAKE,CLARK,JONES
PRESIDENT KING
SALESMAN  ALLEN,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD
```